# quartz autowired field is null

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I've got a `QuartzJobBean`

```
public abstract class SqsQueueListener extends QuartzJobBean {

    @Value("test-queue")
    private String queueName;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonSQS sqsClient;

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        LOGGER.info("Attempt to get message for SQS queue for client: [{}].", sqsClient);
        GetQueueUrlResult result = sqsClient.getQueueUrl(queueName);
    }

    protected abstract void notificationAction(String message);

}
```

I have its non-abstract implementation that extends that class but nothing special there.
It expected to `autowire` sqsClient.

`SqsClient` is created using `FactoryBean`

```
<bean id="sqsClient" class="pack.SqsClientFactoryBean"/>
```

In logs it shows me message that object was successfully created so the factory itself works.

The `xml` configuration looks like this

```
<bean id="sqsProcessingJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="pack.RuleReloadingSqsService"/>
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map> 
            <entry key="sqsClient" value="sqsClient"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sqsTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="sqsProcessingJob"/>
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="10000"/>
</bean>

<bean class="pack.quartz.DisablingSchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="sqsTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However when I run my application I get `sqsClient` as `null`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the setter for `sqsClient` field.

```
private AmazonSQS sqsClient;

@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {}

public void setSqsClient(AmazonSQS sqsClient) {
    this.sqsClient = sqsClient;
}
```